# Was Krishna having second thoughts about the war and the instructions he gave?

Tags: mahabharata

Even in the Gita some on instructions and questions he specifically states are only his opinion.

After the war Krishna finds time to contemplate on dharma and takes a nap his body sheers in pain, thinking about all the suffering his dharma caused. He is dreaming about people telling him about their dharma.

Was he doubting his own lessons, did he come to any new revelations, particularly on the dharma?

Comment: Why did you think he was having second thoughts?

Comment: I do not think that. It's simply as the story goes..

Comment: I do not see anything about second thoughts. Could you quote the relevant verse?

Comment: You need to say exactly where you are reading this from. The way it is written, it is only hearsay. God does not have second thoughts as God knows all that will be before it happens.

Comment: I'm talking about a part of mahabarata where Krishna dreams about various people telling them about dharma... Read the description. Before that Krishna body shivers from the pain his actions (dharma caused)